# Не меняется название поля в JSON файле

Tags: c#

Я создал кортеж и именовал поля. После заполнения кортежа сделал сериализацию и записал в файл, но когда я просмотрел этот файл там вместо именнованых полей Item.
Программный код:

```
 public class AirPollution
    {
        public string post;
        public class Indication
        {
            public string aqi;
            public string CO;
            public string PM2and5;
            public string PM10;
            public DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        }

    }

    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] pos = new string[] { "Пост Кирова", "Пост Маршала Жукова", "Пост Ленина", "Пост Первомайская", "Пост Крылова" };
            AirPollution.Indication [] indicatepoll = new AirPollution.Indication[pos.Length];
            AirPollution[]pol = new AirPollution[pos.Length];
            (string aqi, string CO, string PM2and5, string PM10)[][] tuples = new (string aqi, string CO, string PM2and5, string PM10)[pos.Length][];
            (string post, (string, string, string, string)[] indication)[] tuple = new (string post, (string, string, string, string)[] indication)[pos.Length];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < pos.Length; i++)
            {
                pol[i] = new AirPollution();
                pol[i].post = pos[i];
                poll[i] = new AirPollution.Indication();
                poll[i].aqi = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(0, 500));
                poll[i].CO = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(0, 20) + "%");
                poll[i].PM2and5 = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(0, 20) + "%");
                poll[i].PM10 = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(0, 20) + "%");
                for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                {
                    tuples[i] = new (string aqi, string CO, string PM2and5, string PM10)[1];
                    tuples[i][j] = (poll[i].aqi, poll[i].CO, poll[i].PM2and5, poll[i].PM10);
                    tuple[i] = (pol[i].post, indication:tuples[i]);
                }
            }
            string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tuple);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\jjkjk\\Desktop\\DataSimulation.json");
            writer.Write(js);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Через класс я пытался сделать так:

```
 public class AirPollution
    {
        public string post;
        public string aqi;
        public string CO;
        public string PM2and5;
        public string PM10;
        public DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] pos = new string[] { "Пост Кирова", "Пост Маршала Жукова", "Пост Ленина", "Пост Первомайская", "Пост Крылова" };
            AirPollution[] pol = new AirPollution[pos.Length];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < pos.Length; i++)
            {
                pol[i] = new AirPollution();
                pol[i].post = pos[i];
                pol[i].aqi = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(0, 500));
                pol[i].CO = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(0, 20) + "%");
                pol[i].PM2and5 = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(0, 20) + "%");
                pol[i].PM10 = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(0, 20) + "%");
            }
            string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pol);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\jjkjk\\Desktop\\DataSimulation.json");
            writer.Write(js);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

В этом случае структура в json выходит такая:

```
[{"post":"Пост Кирова","aqi":"161","CO":"3%","PM2and5":"7%","PM10":"2%","date":"2020-05-18T17:21:57.6419238+07:00"}]
```

А нужна такая:

```
[{"post":"Пост Кирова","Indication":[{"aqi":"418","CO":"19%","PM2and5":"3%","PM10":"6%", "date":"2020-05-18T17:21:57.6419238+07:00"}]}
```

Comment: Вы сами себе палки в колеса ставите этими кортежами. Они предназначены не для таких целей, используйте их с умом. Тут же, создайте класс, который будет содержать в себе все необходимое и работайте с ним!

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ при использовании класса у меня не получается нужная структура

Comment: Значит не правильно делаете классы, показывайте что делали, что должно получится и как работаете с JSON

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ отредактировал вопрос и всё отразил

Comment: Вы мне не показали как вы сериализуете в класс и что в итоге у вас получается и что в итоге должно быть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Давайте взглянем на [нужную структуру](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ie5e.png) и разберем все ошибки: Первым идет у вас массив неких классов, где внутри класса должно быть свойство `post` (тип `string`) и свойство `Indication` (тип массив/коллекция класса). Вы же просто делаете массив класса `AirPollution` и что то другое ожидали?

Comment: На скорую руку набросал [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/myFa3Y), как видите без картежей, с понятными классами и получил нужную вам структуру. P.S. Не добавляйте проценты в JSON! Символ `%` это для удобства пользователя, что бы он понимал "Ага, это проценты", вам же допустим если надо будет делать подсчет, что, опять удалять символ? Также используйте в JSON правильный тип, например `aqi` содержит только число, а значит это `int`, другие значения тоже если уберете знак `%` будут `int`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне получается нужно сделать вложенный класс или свойство?

Comment: Конечно, ведь у вас JSON состоит из нескольких же объектов, верно? Нужную вам структуру я показал, на ее основе делайте дальше что надо. Только я там забыл, что первый объект - массив, а значит не `new Root()`, а `new Root[]`, но это думаю уже разберетесь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо